# How to reverse wp pages links?

Tags: blog-page

Every wp page has link structure like http:/site.com/?paged=1,2,3..50(last)

But how exchange it on http:/site.com/?paged=50,49,48..1(last)

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: why would you want to do that? database starts counting from 1, and not from some number... how would you decide from which number to start?

Comment: @Michail: I assume you are talking about paged lists, like archives? You want the earliest post always on the page numbered "1", so they stay the same, even if new posts appear? (Otherwise they get moved to next pages, which might be confusing if you follow an older link)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this by first reversing the sorting order (filter `posts_orderby`), and then reversing the selected posts (filter `the_posts`). By doing this double reverse you circumvent the problem that you have to know the number of posts your query will return before you execute the query.

Keep in mind that WordPress (I think via the canonical rewriter) will remove the `/page/1` part of your URL, so you should prevent this from happening. Also sticky posts might need attention. See the code for `WP_Query::get_posts()` for hooks to change the post query.